# Run pipeline on Openshift Online

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, openshift, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I'm trying to run a simple Pipeline on Openshift Online. Here are my steps:

1. `oc new-project ess`
2. Content of `bc.yaml`:

   ```
   kind: "BuildConfig"
   apiVersion: "v1"
   metadata:
      name: "yngwuoso-pipeline"
   spec:
      source:
      git:
         uri: "https://github.com/yngwuoso/spring-boot-rest-example.git"
   strategy:
      type: JenkinsPipeline
   ```
3. `oc create -f bc.yaml`

The result is:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "bc.yaml": buildconfigs.build.openshift.io "yngwuoso-pipeline" is forbidden: unrecognized build strategy: build.BuildStrategy{DockerStrategy:(*build.DockerBuildStrategy)(nil), SourceStrategy:(*build.SourceBuildStrategy)(nil), CustomStrategy:(*build.CustomBuildStrategy)(nil), JenkinsPipelineStrategy:(*build.JenkinsPipelineBuildStrategy)(nil)}
```

Can anyone tell me what's missing?

Comment: Do you need to spell out the full thing `JenkinsPipelineStrategy`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run `pipeline` build based on `git` source code, first create the `buildConfig` of `source` `Strategy` for git repo, then create the `buildConfig` of `pipeline` to control over the all `build` process.

For instance, it's sample guide for your understanding, it might not work on your env, but you can customize below configuration for your env.

- `buildConfig` for source strategy (`github`) is as follows,

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: BuildConfig
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: yngwuoso-pipeline
      name: yngwuoso-git-build
    spec:
      failedBuildsHistoryLimit: 5
      output:
        to:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          name: yngwuoso-pipeline-image:latest
      runPolicy: Serial
      source:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/yngwuoso/spring-boot-rest-example.git
        type: Git
    strategy:
      sourceStrategy:
        from:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          name: redhat-openjdk18-openshift:1.3
          namespace: openshift
      type: Source
    triggers:
      - type: ConfigChange
      - type: ImageChange
```

- `buildConfig` of `pipeline` for trigger above `buildConfig` based on git repo.

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: BuildConfig
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: yngwuoso-pipeline
      name: yngwuoso-pipeline
    spec:
      runPolicy: Serial
      strategy:
        jenkinsPipelineStrategy:
          jenkinsfile: |-
            node(''){
              stage 'Build by S2I'
                openshiftBuild(namespace: 'PROJECT NAME', bldCfg: 'yngwuoso-git-build', showBuildLogs: 'true')     
            }
        type: JenkinsPipeline
      triggers:
      - github:
          secret: gitsecret
        type: GitHub
      - generic:
          secret: genericsecret
        type: Generic
```

You should configure `GitHub Webhook` using authentication `secret` in `pipeline` `buildConfg`, refer [GitHub Webhooks](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/triggering_builds.html#github-webhooks)
 for more information.

Comment: Thanks Daein, but It sound very complex. I just want Openshift to execute the Pipeline defined in Jenkinsfile defined in the source code (root dir in Git repo). I can do it with the command: oc new-build https://github.com/yngwuoso/spring-boot-rest-example.git --strategy=pipeline. But i wanted to do it low level, creating api resources, just to understand the overall process.

Comment: I know it's not simple usually. But you should make decide how to define the build strategy. For example, using `OpenShift` `buildConfig`(`source strategy`) manner or 3rd party build tool like maven `pom.xml` manner. If you use 3rd party build tool, then you can write pipeline definition which is written as `command` or `script` manner for build in jenkinsfile. This way does not required 2 buildConfig.

Comment: I has introduced above build manner is used by only OpenShift object.  (one buildConfig for defining source build ways, one buildConfig for defining pipeline process which call the buildConfig as defined first one.)

Comment: I also introduce sample to build pipeline here: https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/examples/jenkins/pipeline/samplepipeline.yaml#L97-L210, you can verify 2 buildConfig is required to build either there. It's usual way on pipeline build, AFAIK.